# Variable N is unbound, P is unused, how to solve?

Tags: erlang

I have started learning Erlang and I have got on to mailbox and servers, I've run into an error with my code that i don't understand

```
start()->
Counter = spawn(fun counter/0),
client(Counter).

counter(N) ->
receive
    {get_state, P} -> P!N;
    {inc_state} -> N+1
end.

client(P) ->
N!get_state,
    timer:sleep(100 + rand:uniform(900)),
N!inc_state,
    timer:sleep(100 + rand:uniform(900)),
done.
```

I get unbound error on N and unused on P.

Comment: Did you mean to write `P!get_state` and `P!inc_state` in `client/1`?

Comment: In `client/1`, either `P` should be `N` or the other way round.

Comment: Ah, i just realised :_;

Answer (score 0):

```
-module(counter).

-compile([export_all]).

    start()->
        Counter = spawn(fun counter/0),
        client(Counter).

    % you have started your counter without parameter, (this is the meaning of
    % counter/0) this intermediate function call the counter with the init value 0.
    counter() -> counter(0).

counter(10) ->
    io:format("counter has reach 10, it stops~n");
counter(N) ->
    NewCount = receive
        {get_state, P} ->
            % send the answer
            P ! N,
            % and keep the state unchanged
            N;
        {inc_state} ->
            N+1
    end,
    % never forget to do a recursive loop if you want that your process keep alive!
    counter(NewCount).

client(stop) ->
    io:format("client has not receive any answer, it stops~n");
client(P) ->
    % the pid of your server is P, and you have to respect your message definition,
    % what is expected by the server
    % in your code you are using N instead, which is undefined (unbound),
    % and you don't use P: this is the reason of the error and warning messages.
    P ! {get_state,self()},
    timer:sleep(100 + rand:uniform(900)),
    % add this to show that the state is incrementing
    Continue = receive
        State ->
            io:format("state is ~p~n",[State]),
            P
        after 1000 ->
            stop
    end,
    P ! {inc_state},
    timer:sleep(100 + rand:uniform(900)),
    % recursive loop otherwise it will stop at the first step, leaving a counter process alive.
    % my proposal to stop these processes.
    client(Continue).
```

Comment: Thanks for this Pascal, to stop the process would you add     NewCount == 10 -> stop to terminate the loop?

Comment: Well, this would stop the counter, but not the client. If you have no other requirement, you can add also a timeout in the client receive statement, so it stops if it has no response.

Comment: Hi, i've tried to add a counter to the code, can you have a gander at it ? https://pastebin.com/yMTxHdPw

Comment: When you write some code in erlang you have to remember that any statement returns a value, I used it in the 2 receive blocs. Also, it is very frequent to execute different cases using pattern matching in the different function clauses (like client(stop) to do what must be done on stop condition and client(P) for all other cases.